# Extract words from the text by index into a new column Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe:

```
data = {'text': ['They say that all cats land on their feet, but this does not apply to my cat. He not only often falls, but also jumps badly. We have visited the veterinarian more than once with dislocated paws and damaged internal organs.',
                'Mom called dad, and when he came home, he took moms car and drove to the store'],
       'begin_end':[[128, 139],[20,31]]}
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to use an array from the `begin_end` column to extract the words from the `text` column into a new column, like `text[128:139+1]`. So it will be:

```
    begin_end     new_col
0   [128, 139]  have visited
1   [20, 31]    when he came
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a loop:

```
df['new_col'] = [s[a:b+1] for s, (a,b) in zip(df['text'], df['begin_end'])]
```

output:

```
                                                text   begin_end       new_col
0  They say that all cats land on their feet, but...  [128, 139]  have visited
1  Mom called dad, and when he came home, he took...    [20, 31]  when he came
```

Comment: Doesn't using a loop make the process slower?

Comment: @ErselEr slower than what? There is no vectorial way of doing this. Using a list comprehension will be the fastest, `apply` is performing a loop and is slower than a list comprehension.

Comment: yes I meant slower than `apply`. Didn't know that, I will check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in very easy and simple way

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['They say that all cats land on their feet, but this does not apply to my cat. He not only often falls, but also jumps badly. We have visited the veterinarian more than once with dislocated paws and damaged internal organs.',
                    'Mom called dad, and when he came home, he took moms car and drove to the store'],
           'begin_end':[[128, 139],[20,31]]})
    data
output :

    text                                                  begin_end
    0   They say that all cats land on their feet, but...   [128, 139]
    1   Mom called dad, and when he came home, he took...   [20, 31]
```

Apply function

```
def getString(string,location):
    if location[0] < location[1]: ##checking condtion #you can apply more conditions
        return string[location[0]:location[1]+1]
data['new_col']= data.apply(lambda x : getString(x['text'],x['begin_end']),axis=1)
data
```

output:

```
    text                                             begin_end  new_col
0   They say that all cats land on their feet, but...   [128, 139]  have visited
1   Mom called dad, and when he came home, he took...   [20, 31]    when he came
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['begin'] = df['begin_end'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['end'] = df['begin_end'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['text'][x['begin']:x['end']+1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
 text    begin_end  begin  end       new_col
0 ...   [128, 139]    128  139  have visited
1 ...     [20, 31]     20   31  when he came
```

If `begin` and `end` are already stored separately, you do not need to extract them from the `begin_end`. If it is not necessary, try to avoid storing a `list` in a `pd.Series()`